# Unity launcher not displayed when mirror displays selected

Tags: unity, display

I have my laptop plugged into the TV running at resolution 1024x768. When I open the display settings and select Mirror Displays the launcher bar disappears. If I clear the setting the launcher reappears and I can use the launcher placement dropdown to select the screen to display it on.

How can I get Mirror Displays working with the Unity Launcher?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).